# Hide input label on hover & while typing

Tags: jquery, forms, hover

I have created a form field like so:

```
<p>
<label for="your-name" style="display: block; ">Your name</label>
<span>
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" class="" size="40">
</span>
</p>
```

This code cannot be changed. I have absolutely positioned the label over the field and I have applied jQuery to hide this when I hover over the field like so:

```
jQuery('form p').hover(
   function() {
        jQuery(this).find("label").hide();
   },
   function() {
        jQuery(this).find("label").show();    
    }
);
```

However this only works while mouse is hovering over field. Is there a way to hide the label if typing in the field and on hover?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: I know you can't change the markup, but a native `placeholder` attribute (along with a [polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js)) would have been much easier!

Comment: so a user without javascript just can't use the site?

Comment: Well in my opinion, in 2012 everyone should have JS enabled so I will just be catering for with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats a pretty messy way of doing that.. this is how i would do it:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="your-name" id="your_name" value="Your Name" class="" size="40">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#your_name').focus(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == 'Your Name'){
      $(this).val('');
  }
}).blur(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == ''){
      $(this).val('Your Name');
  }
});
```

or use place holder like james mentioned

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its a plugin so cannot really adjust markup. If I put the default values in it will validate which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your existing method, you can do something like this :

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/SLjMn/

Comment: when you hover over "p", it will hide the label.
When you do typing, it will hide the label.